# How can I 'speak' to a var through a string

Tags: xcode, string, swift, var

I really don't know how to describe my question better than in the title, but i hope you understand it with this code (the second lowest line shows what i want to do, but i don't know how to do in Swift):

```
var titlesZeneggen = ["Zeneggen", "Dienstleistungen", "Erlebnis", "Gastronomie", "Unterkunft", "Kalender", "Multimedia", "Wetter/Webcams", "Orte"]
var titlesDienstleistungen = ["Zeneggen", "Dienstleistungen", "Erlebnis", "Gastronomie", "Unterkunft", "Kalender", "Multimedia", "Wetter/Webcams", "Orte"]
var titlesErlebnis = ["Zeneggen", "Dienstleistungen", "Erlebnis", "Gastronomie", "Unterkunft", "Kalender", "Multimedia", "Wetter/Webcams", "Orte"]
var titlesGastronomie = ["Hotel Alpenblick", "Bistro", "in der Nähe"]

var seguedTitle = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationItem.title = seguedTitle
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondMenuCellUI")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    cell.textLabel?.text = var(named: "titles" + self.seguedTitle)[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

I want that my titles change to whatever seguedTitle is. seguedTitle is given by the previous view. Possible Strings seguedTitle can be: "Zeneggen", "Dienstleistungen", "Erlebnis" etc.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: There is no language feature to do that. You will need to structure your app differently.

Comment: I can do it with a few 'if' and then 'else if' statements but then the code is really long. Is there really no possibility to do that?

Comment: What about using a dictionary? Then you can look up values using a string key.

Comment: Or an enum with switch

Comment: Can i add an array to a key in a dictionary? (Multiple values to one key)

Comment: absolutely you can. `let myDict = [ 'key' : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]`

Comment: or a dictionary: `let myDictionaryOfDictionaries = [ 'key' : [ 'key1' : 1, 'key2' : 2 ] ]` Dictionary keys can be anything. (Array, Dictionary, tuple, function, struct, class instance, etc)

Comment: Good. Thats a very nice solution then! Let's try it out. Thanks

Comment: @nielsbot Dictionary keys must implement the `Hashable` protocol.

Comment: Sorry--I meant values, not keys

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that I think will do what you want.

```
var titles[
    "Zeneggen" : ["Zeneggen", "Dienstleistungen", "Erlebnis", "Gastronomie", "Unterkunft", "Kalender", "Multimedia", "Wetter/Webcams", "Orte"],
    "Dienstleistungen" : ["Zeneggen", "Dienstleistungen", "Erlebnis", "Gastronomie", "Unterkunft", "Kalender", "Multimedia", "Wetter/Webcams", "Orte"],
    "Erlebnis" : ["Zeneggen", "Dienstleistungen", "Erlebnis", "Gastronomie", "Unterkunft", "Kalender", "Multimedia", "Wetter/Webcams", "Orte"],
    "Gastronomie" :["Hotel Alpenblick", "Bistro", "in der Nähe"]
]

var seguedTitle = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationItem.title = seguedTitle
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Make sure that the title is really there.
    if let tableData = titles[self.seguedTitle] as? [String] {
        return tableData.count
    }
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondMenuCellUI")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    if let tableData = titles[self.seguedTitle] as? [String] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution! I will try this out tonight.